# Electron + React, how do you "link" variables between jsx and main.js/renderer.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, electron

I'm using Electron with React and started implementing some basic components like input text.
Before that I was using Electron without react, and made things work with the renderer.js like this :

```
const item = document.getElementById('MyItem');
function OnMyOwnEvent({target : {value}})
{
  window.API.ownEvent(value); // API and ownEvent declared in Preload.js
}
```

And in Main.js, I could retrieve the value like this :
ipcMain.handle('ownEvent', (_event, value) => ...

But with React, getElementById does not work as it seems to get elements from the index.html file, (but now all the elements have moved to App.jsx).

So my question is, how do you get values changed from App.jsx to Main.js?

Comment: What does `document.getElementById` have to do with this? You aren't even _using_ `item` in your example code. (Plus, the elements still exist in your DOM, but probably not immediately - you have to wait until React rendered everything.

Comment: document.getElementById was the way I did things before using react, and it worked fine. I just put the code needed for explaining my point.
Now I'm just trying to understand how I access component values changed from jsx to main.js

Comment: How was used `OnMyOwnEvent`?

Comment: in preload.js :   OnMyOwnEvent    : (arg) => ipcRenderer.invoke('ownEvent', arg),
in main.js :
if (ipcMain.handle('ownEvent', (_event, value) => {
...
}

Comment: @Grit I meant on the renderer. Also please edit your question to add information, do not put code as comment.